# How to make a Bitcoin address your main one in Blockchain.info?

Tags: blockchain.info

On the Your Wallet starting page of Blockchain.info, there is a frame with the text

```
This is your Bitcoin address
*bitcoin address here*
Share it with anyone and they can sent you money.
```

(or something like that, I don't exactly know what it is in English, I am using it in Dutch)

I have 2 addresses specified, one with 0.01306288 BTC and one with zero BTC. The one with 0.01306288 BTC is shown in the frame on the start page, but I would rather have the other one.
Is there a way to make the other address show up there?

Comment: You shouldn't care. I.e. if you care about using a new address at each receiving transaction, you (unless I'm mistaken) are supposed to do it manually in the "receive money" tab. If you don't care, you don't care so just use that address whichever it is.

Comment: @Lohoris No, I don't want to use a different address per transaction. I just want to have the address I use as my main one show up on the start page.

Answer (score 1):

I've played around with the blockchain.info wallet, and here's what it looks like is happening:

Blockchain.info shows the "This Is Your Bitcoin Address" by date the address was added to your wallet (not the date of the oldest transaction on the blockchain)

To determine blockchain.info's "sort order" for your addresses, export a paper wallet (from the button on the "Wallet Home" tab)

The order of addresses on that pdf is the order Blockchain.info will use when choosing your Default Address. You need to archive/remove all of the addresses above your DESIRED address for it to be your default.

So if you want to change the default address you have two options:

### If you don't need the 'old' address anymore

Simply transfer the BTC out of the previous address into a new one (either one you already have, or click on the 'create new address' button).

Archive the 'old' address. It's still available in your wallet under the Receive Money / Archived tab.

Archived addresses won't be shown as your main address.

### If you want to keep the 'old' address in your wallet

A little bit trickier, you'll be DELETING the address & private key, then re-adding it.

1. Generate your paper wallet backup, and have it open. Make SURE you have the private key of the address(es) in front of you.
2. Archive the address(es) above your desired address
3. Go to the 'Archive' tab and find those archived addresses. Check the box next to them and select DELETE. (blockchain.info will ask you if you're sure. Then they triple check. It's a good idea to make sure that yes - you still have the private keys saved from step 1 above)
4. Re-import the private keys taken from your paper wallet) for your addresses. It's under the "Import / Export" tab. When importing, select IMPORT KEYS DIRECTLY (instead of SWEEP KEYS) if you want to keep the same address in your wallet.

Answer (score 0):

So far the best method I've found to accomplish this is to go to your address book in the blockchain.info android application and dwell/long-press on the address entry and select set as default address. I've poured over the web application and can't seem to find the equivalent function. Hope this helps.

"You shouldn't care." is possibly *the* most useless answer I have ever wasted my time reading. Everyone is entitled to manage their personal wealth however they see fit.